# Variable selection question

Tags: feature-selection

In regression where there are multiple predictors $x_1, x_2, \dots$ let's say our feature selection algorithm (lasso, forward stepwise, etc.) returns that $x_1$ is an important predictor, but our client says there's no way $x_1$ is important. What could be happening?

Comment: Does x1 appear to have good predictive power on a test set?

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities and without details it is impossible to say which is most likely.  Here are a few:

1. You are observing a Type I error, i.e. there really is no relationship but due to chance the data observed shows a relationship.  With a single test (and all assumptions holding) this will happen with probability $\alpha$.  In multiple testing (stepwise procedures) it will happen more often.  Violated assumptions can also increase the risk of a type I error.
2. You are missing a lurking variable that is related to both $y$ and $x_1$.  It could be true that $x_1$ does not cause y, but that something else causes both $y$ and $x_1$ and therefore there is a relationship when that something else is not accounted for.
3. Data entry error.  A single outlier in both $x_1$ and $y$ will make them appear related using the least squares methodology.  Or $x_1$ is really a different variable that does relate to $y$, but is labeled wrong.
4. Your client now has an opportunity to learn something new because despite their understanding, there really is an unexpected relationship.
5. Something else.
6. Some combination of the above.

Comment: Good list (+1). Clear, incisive comments plus a light touch.